# NextJS TypeScript getStaticProps typing

Tags: typescript, next.js

I just started learning NextJS and TypeScript, by following the official NextJS docs about [Data Fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) and the `getStaticProps` function with types. In their example they used this aproach to get suggestions based on the type of the `Posts` component props:

```js
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  // ... fetching the posts (returns an array) ...
    
  return {
    props: {          
      posts
    }
  }
}

const Posts = ({ posts }: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => { 
   // ... posts type is inferred ...
}
```

I undestand that what they are doing is infering the type of the posts props (in this case an array of individual posts), but before reading their proposed way of doing it I came up with my way:

```js
interface Post {
  // ... created a Post interface ...
}

interface Props {
  posts: Post[]
}

const Posts: React.FC<Props> = ({ posts }) => {
  // ... TS still knows what posts should have (its an array) ...
}
```

I know that this two ways of doing this are different, they are infering the type of the props based on the request's return value, but my question is: Why would I infer my prop's type, shouldn't I always expect it to return a specific type of value? I get that by using their approach I am being more flexible with the type of value that I'm receiving, but wouldn't an approach like mine be more secure and clear?

(Thanks in advance) As I told you, I'm getting started with both Next and TypeScript, I don't know if this is the only-Next way of doing this or is a TypeScript practice, please let me know if you have more experience than me in any of these technologies.